# Hilos sencillos en Java con archivos

Tags: java, hilos, filewriter

Tengo unos archivos de texto lo que van a tener es formulas simples como 2+2, 6*90, etc. Cada archivo tiene que ser leído por un hilo (por cada archivo vamos a crear un hilo) que se va a encargar de leer el contenido del archivo y realizar los cálculos. Finalmente se debe de imprimir el resultado en pantalla como algo asi deberia mostrar

```
Archivo1
2+2
4
```

Lo estoy implementando de esta manera

```
  public class Entrada implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    FileReader entrada = null;
    try {
        String linea = "";
        entrada = new FileReader("C:/Users/CALCULO1.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada);
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(linea);
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public class Salida implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    FileWriter salida = null;
    try {
        String linea = "";
        salida = new FileWriter("salida.txt");
        BufferedWriter d = new BufferedWriter(salida);


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Entrada d = new Entrada();
    Thread hilo = new Thread(d);
    hilo.start();
    Salida d1 = new Salida();
    Thread hilo1 = new Thread(d1);
    hilo1.start();
}
```

Comment: Y cual seria el problema? hay algun error?

Comment: Me imprime la operacion que tengo en el archivo pero no me muestra el resultado

Comment: Pero es que en ningún momento estás intentando parsear la operación que lees del fichero. Tienes que leer la operación, parserla, luego intentar ejecutarla. Si las operaciones con sencillas(solo un operador) no hay problema, pero si no es así, se complica la cosa, no es trivial.

Comment: Son operaciones con diferente operador para eso utilizo expresiones regulares algo asi:  `String REGEX = "^[0-9\\-\\+\\*\\/\\.]*";`